# reading in values to insert in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, input

I am working on an assignment in which I need to read in sample input from a file and insert it into a 2D array. Here is an example of input:

```
5 6
1 3 4 B 4 3
0 3 5 0 0 9
0 5 3 5 0 2
4 3 4 0 0 4
0 2 9 S 2 1
```

The 5 and 6 are the dimensions of the array. The user must be able to input many arrays like this one at once, the program ends when the user inputs -1. This is the code I have so far that doesn't seem to be working as it should(I print out the array to make sure the code works):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arHeight = sc.nextInt();
    int arWidth = sc.nextInt();
    sc.useDelimiter(" ");
    String[][] map = new String[arHeight][arWidth];

        for(int i=0; i<arHeight; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<arWidth; j++){
                map[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
            }//end inner for
        }//end outter for 

            for(int i=0; i<arHeight; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<arWidth; j++){
                System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
            }//end inner for
        }//end outter for 
    }
```

The assignment states that I cannot use recursion and that I must use 2D arrays. I have looked at other questions but still can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get right on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you read the whole line i*j times

```
    for(int i=0; i<arHeight; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<arWidth; j++){
            map[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
```

also you keep al the data in a string array and I don't know why. Here is the solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arHeight = sc.nextInt();
    int arWidth = sc.nextInt();

    int[][] map = new int[arHeight][arWidth];

    for(int i=0; i<arHeight; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<arWidth; j++){
            map[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }//end inner for
    }//end outter for

    for(int i=0; i<arHeight; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<arWidth; j++){
            System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
        }//end inner for
    }

}
```

Then try to use

```
char[][] map = new char[arHeight][arWidth];
```

and in the for loop:

```
if(sc.next().charAt(0) != " ") map[i][j] =sc.next().charAt(0);
```

This way you should read all the chars which are not " ".

Comment: I had used a String array because there are two characters in the array, B and S. Would an array of chars work best?

Comment: I will update the answer. I did not observe that you have chars

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help! It seems to be working properly now!